# Django question: regarding Foreign Keys on two separate tables

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

---

[Clear here to view diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkiST.jpg)

Hello, based on a diagram above:

```
class Course(models.Model):
   ...


class Lesson(models.Model):
   course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ...

class Question(models.Model):
   # Foreign KEY TO LESSON
   lesson_id = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete_models.CASCADE) ---> HOW????
   ...
```

How should I assign the '***lesson_id***' in **Question** model to **Lesson** model when the common for both is **Course** model?

Really need help on this I'm new to Programming.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Sorry not sure i understand. Shouldn't `lesson_id` just point to the `Lesson` model? If there are Questions in each Lesson and Lessons in each Course, then I think you'd be fine doing `models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete_models.CASCADE)` (Basically I think your diagram might be wrong and Question should have a line to Lesson, not Course) :)

Comment: Thank you for the response. That's what I though too. But the foreign keys in Lesson and Question point to Course. Then I need have to retrieve/set lesson_id based on those relations.

Comment: How would you associate a Question to a specific Lesson then?

Comment: Please see entire diagram here ->  https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-CD0251EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/m6_final/images/onlinecourse_app_er.png

Comment: The relationship with `Course` to `Lesson` seems to be one-to-many, so `Question` needs to have its own reference to `Lesson` if you want to have `Questions` assigned per `Lesson`

Comment: @TraderMan yeah I really do think the diagram is just wrong.. given it has the field `lesson_id` in the `Question` model, I'd do what I first described.